# Basic RF ping-power transceiver for 100s of nodes

Tags: rf

I'm working on an art piece that intends to emulate fireflies [synchronizing their flashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photinus_carolinus). There will be hundreds of tiny LED nodes hung from a tree each running on a small battery. I'm curious if there is a novel way to use RF to synchronize the flashing. (this could be done with IR, but doing it with RF could let everything be more contained)

The idea is that each node would send a low-power RF ping when it flashes its LED. The ping would not need to contain any data at all. All the other nodes would listen on that frequency in order to time their flashes.  The moment which has the most pings would be seen as the moment to synchronize towards.

I've not done a lot of RF work, so I'm curious how possible this is in a small low power device. Since we don't care about data, would it be possible to simply detect that one moment has more transmitting nodes than other moments? More RF power? I assume there would be too much interference, without going down a mesh network path, to actually receive data.

Comment: I would consider a counter cct. to pulse the 2 to 4 pulses then pause and recycle with an invisible IR burst sent to a daylight blocking PD amplified to trigger a reset.

Comment: How does the 1st node know when to ping if it's listening and none are pinging? RF won't easily work - use light detection.

Comment: I wouldn't even try.,  That's alotta complexity for little return.   I'm also doing an "artsy" firefly thing, and have done in the past.  Having each LED do it's own thing in a random manner looks pretty convincing (to me at least).   I literally got my design director to start crying when she first saw it (she has some history with fireflies apparently).   It's the control of the fade-in-fade-out that really matters (again IMO)... get that right, and make them truly random, and you'll have a very realistic display.

Comment: Not really... a big part of the problem is that receiving for any length of time costs more energy than transmitting.  Maybe you set them to autonomously run a little fast or slow, and check for a group effect just after/before they would on their own...

Comment: using RF for sync would cause all the devices to flash in unison

Comment: you could do what you want by using wired addressable LEDs ... use a microcontroller or a computer to give them "flock mind" ... the complicated part would be determining where each LED is positioned inside the flock ... the position could be determined by the use of a webcam feeding into a CV program that determines where each LED is in space ... it would not be an easy project to implement, but probably doable ... sort of like a freeform 3D LED cube

Comment: The Male firefly needs that synchronous dark time to see the fainter female in the distance respond to the ping, so an IR detector to reset the timer with a sender may work such as with a remote Rx IC.

Comment: To avoid the 100’s of batteries consider twisted pair AWG 30 magnet wire for power.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using RF, you might get *some* joy from super-regenerative receiver circuits. These normally pulse at supersonic frequencies. Circuit time constants *could* be slowed to pulse-per-second.

- Very simple circuit having just a few transistors
- Low power drain from a few battery cell
- Super-regen circuits are both **transmitter** and **receiver** combined.
- Range possible: tens-of-meters (a guess)

Super regenerative receivers are notorious for causing interference with one another when their RF is tuned to the same frequency. This is exactly the action that you are after. You may be able to get them to self-sync, or at least affect one another.

Getting a super-regen to pulse its RF at one or two second intervals may be difficult. It is possible to build a super-regen around a tiny microcontroller. The timing functions of *any* microcontroller would be used to delay the RF sync pulse. The microcontroller could also sense pulses from other super-regens. See: http://www.eix.co.uk/Articles/Radio/Welcome.htm

 Dr. Eddie Insam includes a super-regen externally-quenched microcontroller circuit idea, among others:
[image: Dr.Eddie Insam super-regenerative receiver]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using a photo-diode to detect when another node flashes.  Photo-diodes are cheap (like pennies).

Even a cheap RF transceiver will be a few dollars per node, but if you really want to use one Hope RF makes some off the shelf RF transciever PCBs that are about 1" square that work really well.

I have used the RFM75-S.

When I tested it, it worked well up to several hundred feet.
It has a simple SPI interface and requires minimal software.
It has a built in PCB trace antenna.
The cost was low (about $2.30 each).